# Get the time out of Kivy MDTimePicker

Tags: time, kivy, picker

I am new to Kivy and widget binding.
I found the following code on Github that presents a time picker with a nice clock.

It should be simple but I just don't get how to modify the program to simply print out the time.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDTimePicker

KV = '''
FloatLayout:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Time 1"
        pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'y': .95}
        on_release: app.show_time_picker1()
'''
class Clock(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def show_time_picker1(self):
        '''Open time picker dialog.'''
        time_dialog1 = MDTimePicker()
        time_dialog1.bind(time=self.get_time)
        time_dialog1.open()

    def get_time(self, instance, time):
        '''
        The method returns the set time.
        :type instance: <kivymd.uix.picker.MDTimePicker object>
        :type time: <class 'datetime.time'>
        '''
        return time

Clock().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `print` to the `get_time()` method:

```
def get_time(self, instance, time):
    '''
    The method returns the set time.
    :type instance: <kivymd.uix.picker.MDTimePicker object>
    :type time: <class 'datetime.time'>
    '''
    print('picked time is', time)
    return time
```